# Why isn't SFTP logging working?

Tags: ssh, sftp

I'm missing something simple, I think, with SFTP logging.

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -f AUTH -l INFO
```

also, I've got

```
Match Group customers
#   ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

so note this **isn't** a chroot problem.  What I see in the logs are

```
May  9 15:48:32 oc8703477275 sshd[22927]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user customer by (uid=0)
May  9 15:48:42 oc8703477275 sshd[22927]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user customer
```

I ran sshd -ddd and rsyslog -dn so I could see the chatter.  After the login, both sshd and rsyslog are quiet while I change directories, move files around, etc -- and obviously none of that is being logged.

Where should I look?

**update** Martin provided the bingo.  It looks like the ForceCommand overrides the settings on subsystem.  Adding the -l INFO there fixed it.

Comment: You should look at your syslog configuration.

Comment: You do not have the `-l INFO` in `ForceCommand` in the `Match`.